# Add custom content for a specific product on WooCommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce, How can I add a custom content for a specific product on single product pages?

Here is an explicit screen shot:
[image: How can i add a content for single product page]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As your screenshot is not so clear on where you want this custom content you have 2 options:

**1) Under the product price**

With this custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_before_single_product_summary`** action hook you can add some custom content **to a specific product ID** *(to be defined in the function)* this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_content_for_specific_product', 15 );
function add_custom_content_for_specific_product() {
    global $product;

    // Limit to a specific product ID only (Set your product ID below )
    if( $product->get_id() != 37 ) return;

    // The content start below (with translatables texts)
    ?>
        <div class="custom-content product-id-<?php echo $product->get_id(); ?>">
            <h3><?php _e("My custom content title", "woocommerce"); ?></h3>
            <p><?php _e("This is my custom content text, this is my custom content text, this is my custom content text…", "woocommerce"); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php
    // End of content
}
```

**2) Under the product image:**

With this custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_before_single_product_summary`** action hook you can add some custom content **to a specific product ID** *(to be defined in the function)* this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_content_for_specific_product', 25 );
function add_custom_content_for_specific_product() {
    global $product;

    // Limit to a specific product ID only (Set your product ID below )
    if( $product->get_id() != 37 ) return;

    // The content start below (with translatables texts)
    ?>
        <div class="custom-content product-id-<?php echo $product->get_id(); ?>">
            <h3><?php _e("My custom content title", "woocommerce"); ?></h3>
            <p><?php _e("This is my custom content text, this is my custom content text, this is my custom content text…", "woocommerce"); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php
    // End of content
}
```

If you want to remove the product short description you can add into the function just after the if statement:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works…

Comment: just a small typo - it should be 'functions.php' file not 'function.php'

Answer (score 0):

Just Edit the product to add the content. and that content will show on its detail page.